# Automatically Open A Terminal when ubuntu login

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

When I am using the ubuntu operating system, the most thing I use is a terminal/shell.

As a result, I wonder if a terminal/shell can be opened/popped-up automatically once I login to the desktop.

PS. I know that, we can press Ctrl + Alt + T to open a terminal/shell. However, I want the terminal/shell pop-up without any actions.

PSS. **The comment from [Jeremy H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2487654/jeremy-h) works, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) is the step by step tutorial.**

Comment: probably better to ask on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: There's a site dedicated to questions on Ubuntu use: http://askubuntu.com Stackoverflow is for questions related to computer programming.

Comment: Here is a good step by step for you: 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Answer (score 1):

Based on what is written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) go to `System > Preferences > Startup Applications` and start a terminal or script that launches your terminal.

Comment: In newer versions like ubuntu18, search startup will locate the entrance.